# Docker starts but stops a few seconds later /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused

Tags: docker

Docker stopped working. I tried to remove everything as many posts say and reinstall it properly but it didn't work.
I updated Ubuntu from 16.04 to 20.04 but it didn't change anything.
Here is what journalctl -fu docker returns to me:

```
déc. 11 18:39:46 void systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.698609627+01:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.700702534+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.700740268+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.700775216+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.700796083+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.704464276+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.704490108+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.704516889+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.704534196+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.738711589+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.738816475+01:00" level=info msg="Waiting for containerd to be ready to restart event processing" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.738868976+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.738981253+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.754342509+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.756138569+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.756165078+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.756400319+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.756575852+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.756677845+01:00" level=info msg="Waiting for containerd to be ready to restart event processing" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
déc. 11 18:39:46 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:46.888054465+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
déc. 11 18:39:47 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:47.044514593+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
déc. 11 18:39:47 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:47.081098362+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve containerd version: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\""
déc. 11 18:39:47 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:47.113766739+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=eeddea2 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.0
déc. 11 18:39:47 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:47.113868192+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
déc. 11 18:39:47 void systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
déc. 11 18:39:47 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:47.151815550+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
déc. 11 18:39:47 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:47.739377744+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:47 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:47.739521537+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:49 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:49.260933200+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:49 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:49.394350857+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.759749164+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.792984796+01:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.794171095+01:00" level=warning msg="Error while testing if containerd API is ready" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = grpc: the client connection is closing"
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18721]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.794889281+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon shutdown complete"
déc. 11 18:39:51 void systemd[1]: docker.service: Succeeded.
déc. 11 18:39:51 void systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
déc. 11 18:39:51 void systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.944175893+01:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.946396827+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.946476600+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.946544815+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.946589304+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.951454032+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.951534602+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.951592657+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.951651383+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.989321278+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.989399790+01:00" level=info msg="Waiting for containerd to be ready to restart event processing" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.989443001+01:00" level=info msg="blockingPicker: the picked transport is not ready, loop back to repick" module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.989503094+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.989604731+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.996149262+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.998010017+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.998040915+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.998309289+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.998450880+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
déc. 11 18:39:51 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:51.998557237+01:00" level=info msg="Waiting for containerd to be ready to restart event processing" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
déc. 11 18:39:52 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:52.131616026+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
déc. 11 18:39:52 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:52.296256488+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
déc. 11 18:39:52 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:52.333098112+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve containerd version: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\""
déc. 11 18:39:52 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:52.357598335+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=eeddea2 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.0
déc. 11 18:39:52 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:52.357665258+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
déc. 11 18:39:52 void systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
déc. 11 18:39:52 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:52.384560398+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
déc. 11 18:39:52 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:52.990010515+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:52 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:52.990013141+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:54 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:54.511326415+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:54 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:54.581384653+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:56 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:56.947060840+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
déc. 11 18:39:57 void systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
déc. 11 18:39:57 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:57.042961392+01:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
déc. 11 18:39:57 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:57.044113845+01:00" level=warning msg="Error while testing if containerd API is ready" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = grpc: the client connection is closing"
déc. 11 18:39:57 void dockerd[18882]: time="2020-12-11T18:39:57.044874843+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon shutdown complete"
déc. 11 18:39:57 void systemd[1]: docker.service: Succeeded.
déc. 11 18:39:57 void systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
déc. 11 18:39:57 void systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
déc. 11 18:39:57 void systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
déc. 11 18:39:57 void systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

I searched on many forums and on GitHub but I couldn't find anything functional...